# convert date time stap to date time format in sql

Tags: sql-server-2008

HI I need to change date time stamp to date time format

**date time stamp is "19122012123508" which must be convert as 2012-12-19 12:35:08.000**
**Date time Stamp format "ddmmyyyyhhmmss" to "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.ms"**
Please suggest how will I get desired output.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you'll have to do some string manipulation as that time stamp format isn't a built in format that is recognised by the cast/convert functions.

Assuming the string is always the same length you could try this:

```
DECLARE @input NVARCHAR(20)
SELECT @input = '19122012123508'

SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, 
    SUBSTRING(@input,5,4) + '-' + SUBSTRING(@input,3,2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(@input,1,2) 
    + ' ' + SUBSTRING(@input,9,2) + ':' + SUBSTRING(@input,11,2) 
    + ':' + SUBSTRING(@input,13,2), 120)
```